# Is blog/posts/year/month/day/slug a RESTful URI scheme?

Tags: rest, architecture, uri, web

I know thatt those kind of URIs are good SEO wise, but are they RESTful?
My hunch is that they are not, but I am looking for verification.
The reason that I think that they are not RESTful is because the year, month and day are parameters to a query and the slug is actually the identifier.
Is blog/posts/slug?year=2011&month=9&day=19 a better approach here?
I'm not sure about this.

Comment: There is no such thing as a RESTful or non-RESTful URL.  It is a completely false constraint that I believe comes from single line in an outdated and replaced URI spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the point.  You're worrying about something that REST doesn't care about.  Either scheme is fine so long as the client is obtaining the URLs from hypertext and not constructing them itself according to a scheme.  [Please read this article about this type of misunderstanding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

Comment: Yes. And also, the path components of an HTTP URI are by definition hierarchical. year/month/day/slug makes more sense if year/ and year/month/ and year/month/day/ are also meaningful resource identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You should base the URL on the resource that it identifies, not on the method that you use in the back end of the server to produce the resource.

So, your scheme would work fine to identify blog posts.

The REST principle is not that much concerned with how you identify the resources, only that the verb should not be in the resource identifier, so `GetBlogPost?year=2011&month=9&day=19` would be an example of an URI that is not RESTful.

Answer (score -1):

`blog/posts/year/month/day` is not a resource identifier. Not one that makes senses anyway

So what you want is something like

`mysite.com/posts/<id>`

Or if you want to view all posts on a certain day

`mysite.com/posts?filter=2011/9/19`

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but your first statement is incorrect. It is a perfectly valid resource identifier. The first URI would most likely identify a list of blog posts published on a particular day.  Using year month day in a path segment is perfectly valid because it is a natural hierarchy.   It is unlikely that anyone would want a list of all the posts on feb 2nd regardless of year.  Your example using the query string is also a valid approach, and also the approach I would take.

Comment: @DarrelMiller. meh the resource `posts` does not contain `year`. The resource `year` does not contain `month`. etc. I think its URI abuse

Comment: Feel free to point me to the part of the uri spec that you feel is being violated.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I didn't say anything was violated, it's just not a good uri. You can do better.